# Как перевести HEX в картинку?

Tags: hex

Имеется HEX файл, в котором "зашифрована" картинка. Нужно вновь получить картинку. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Можно написать программу, например. Но что такое в вашем понимании HEX - не понятно.

Comment: Как я писал выше, в программировании я не очень силен. Такую программу, думаю, пока что не осилю. Пример того, что у меня имеется: 
08 50 41 B8 14 B1 09 09 29 8E 36 08 9C 11 96 69 60 28 2D 0E 8E 8E 07 45 E5 EC CD 2E 85 AC CD 2D 4C 25 CF 0F 2F 45 ED 2D AC E5 EC CD EE 8D EC 6D 0D 6C 25 CD 4E 0C E5 5C F9 A3 B3 1E E8 BC 47 2A 86 AC 82 98 26 C8 E5 E0 B2 09 55 FE C8 83 EA 94 96 B9 57 82 82 27 FB 56 2A 7B BF 23 CC C2 58 B0 6F 8D 94 66 E5 3D 2E 72 E6 47 23 62 E3
В моем понимании hex - это шестнадцатеричная сс.

Comment: Если это начало вашего HEX-файла, то на картинку это не похоже.

Comment: А что это может быть? Текстовый файл? Пробовал преобразовать, получался бред :)

Comment: Наверное, потому что это и есть бред? :-)

Comment: Так не должен быть бредом)
Благодарю за помощь)

Answer (score 2):

В общем виде задача "выдать правильное изображение из двоичного представления" решения не имеет, но можно попытаться и даже получить пригодный результат. Для этого сперва надо бы прояснить пару моментов.

#### Неизвестность 1: как представлены пиксели?

Далеко не всегда и вовсе не правило, но с хорошей вероятностью это один из известных форматов (jpg, png, tga, bmp, dds и т.п.). В этом случае можно поискать или написать самостоятельно программу по поиску сигнатур - заголовков и определённых структур, соответствующих этим форматам (стандартные конвертеры знают заголовки, но не ищут их внутри других файлов). Это самый простой случай и если повезёт с "неизвестностью 2", решение найдено.

Другое дело, если картинка изначально хранится в нестандартном виде или с отрезанным заголовком; тут уже придётся угадывать формат. Чтобы иметь возможность правильно интерпретировать набор бит, нужно обладать некоторыми данными: размером (ширина, высота), числом бит на пиксель, наличие палитры или порядка цветовых плоскостей, используется ли сжатие - и это только основное. Прямого решения тут нет, но можно попытаться логически определить структуру данных; возможно, вам повезёт.

#### Неизвестность 2: что означают эти двоичные данные?

- Шифрованный текст

Шифрование означает, что данные нечитаемы без ключа. Значит, есть и ключ, где-то хранящийся, и можно надеяться, что алгоритм стандартный. Если картинка - это ресурс из какой-нибудь игры или программы, скорее всего шифрования нет, как максимум алгоритм - это какой-нибудь быстрый поточный типа XOR с фиксированным значением. XOR обычно можно заметить по повторяющимся последовательностям байтов, и особенно если картинок несколько - по их заголовкам. В других случаях поиск ключа задача нетривиальная. Наличие шифрования, кстати, не исключает ещё и кодирования.

- Кодированное представление

Кодирование видоизменяет представление картинки в потоке байт, что делает простой поиск заголовков непригодным; это может быть как сжатие ([LZ*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77), [Хаффман](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), [ANS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_numeral_systems)), так и просто разбивка на какие-то секции внутри файла для удобства самой программы. Не имея начальных сведений об источнике данных предсказать алгоритм сложно. Имеет смысл смотреть на распределение байт в куске данных - если оно достаточно неравномерно, то кодирования сжатием скорее всего нет (либо это [RLE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

- Данные - это контейнер

Самый простой случай, когда картинку хранят в своего рода "файловой системе" внутри другого файла. В этом случае извлечь картинку можно поиском сигнатур, либо "угадав" строение контейнера (что в целом не так сложно, зная, что где-то должно храниться имя файла, его смещение и размер).

Определившись с этими двумя неизвестностями вы будете знать, как достать кусок двоичных данных с картинкой из файла, и как их потом интерпретировать, чтобы получить на выходе пиксели.

P.S. Если вы знаете, что именно на картинке, которую вы анализируете, это может немного облегчить анализ формата. Вдруг вы заметите на ней артефакты JPEG?